# I have three files and I want to count the concurrences from first 10 lines of the files and summation of it?

Tags: linux, bash

I Used this command to count the concurrences of the entire file.

```
grep -o "pattern" fileName | wc -l
```

I need to find out the numbers of concurrences from only first 10 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `head` to read only first 10 lines of the file.

```
head -n 10 fileName | grep -o "pattern" | wc -l
```

or just

```
head -n 10 fileName | grep -c "pattern"
```

Comment: Awesome, Feel free to accept the answer if its fine. Thanks!

Comment: c.f. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)